# Можете объяснить, что обозначает данное действие? (раньше такого не встречал)

Tags: java, циклы, переменные

Внизу представлен целый код, который выводит значения многомерного массива 4x5:
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int twoD[][] = new int[4][5];
        int i, j, k = 0;
         for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
          for (j=0; j < 5; j++) {
           twoD[i][j] = k;
           k++;
    
      }    
       for (i=0; i < 4; i++) { 
        for (j=0; j < 5; j++)
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " "); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }
   }

}
```

Мне не понятно одно действие в этом коде, а именно:

```
twoD[i][j] = k;
```

Затем идет оператор увеличения операнда на единицу.
Причём, если закоментировать эту строку, то выводится все по нулям.

Интересно, что же это строчка кода делает? Можете объяснить?

Comment: заполняет массив значениями от 0 до N

Comment: поподробнее можно?

Comment: всё, понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта строка заполняет массив, то есть здесь `twoD[i][j] = k;` значение `k` присваивается в позицию `j` массива `i` (так как у вас массив массивов). То есть ваша программа в первом блоке кода

```
for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            twoD[i][j] = k;
            k++;
    }
}
```

заполняет массив массивов значениями `k`, а затем выводит на экран все значения. Если  вы за комментируете эту строку `twoD[i][j] = k;` тогда ваш массив не заполниться никакими значениями, а на экран выведутся нули так как они заполняют массив `int` по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Одномерный массив выглядит так:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```

Это можно считать как 7 столбцов и один ряд

В двумерном массиве добавляются ряды:

```
    j = 0...<5
    --------------
 i  |00 01 02 03 04 
 =  |10 11 12 13 14 
 0  |20 21 22 23 24 
... |30 31 32 33 34 
< 4 |
```

Каждая строка - это значение `i`, а каждая колонка - значение `j`

Вот и получается, что в `[i][j]` в массив индексом `i` (строка номер `i`) в колонке индексом `j` (столбец номер `j`) положить значение `k`